# What is PHP's parse_ini_file() scanner mode?

Tags: php

PHP 5.3 added a `$scanner_mode` parameter to `parse_ini_file()`.  What is it?

The documentation isn't very useful:

> **scanner_mode**
>
> Can either be `INI_SCANNER_NORMAL` (default) or `INI_SCANNER_RAW`. If `INI_SCANNER_RAW` is supplied, then option values will not be parsed.

What is an "option value" in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe RAW will not do any parsing of the values, so "on"/"off" will not be understood as true/false and would require using "1" and "0"

"option" in this case, I think refers to the value of each ini key/value pair.

Comment: from the docs `Constants may also be parsed in the ini file so if you define a constant as an ini value before running parse_ini_file(), it will be integrated into the results. Only ini values are evaluated.`

Comment: Interesting.  I didn't realize that `parse_ini_file()` even did this.  I had just assumed that it returned strings for everything.  All this time I've been using `filter_var()` unnecessarily.  :-)  Thanks!